# C++ Pipe [How to get ipaddress or hostname of connected client.]

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, pipe

I wanna get client ip address or host name.
I'm using VS6.0 & VS2010 on Windows 7 Ultimate.

> `CreateNamedPipe(...)` on Server is as follows :

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {0};
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe( 
    _T("\\\\.\\pipe\\AnonymousPipe"),   // pipe name 
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,  
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
    0xD000, 
    0xD000, 
    NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, 
    &sa);

if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError()); 
    return -1;
}

fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ? TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED); 

if (fConnected) 
{ 
    printf("Client connected, creating a processing thread.\n");

    // Get Information Of Connected Client.
    // Client Ip Address or Hostname.
}
```

How can I detect which client connected to server?
I can see the connection between server and client using `netstat` cmd line.

```
netstat -an|find "445"
TCP     0.0.0.0:445     0.0.0.0:0               LISTENING
TCP     0.0.0.0:445     192.168.125.115:4124    ESTABLISHED
TCP     0.0.0.0:445     192.168.125.192:4882    ESTABLISHED
```

String "192.168.125.115"&"192.168.125.192" is my target.
But I cannot find a way to detect connected client ip in programmatically in VS6.0.

Someone told me that use GetNamedPipeClientComputerName() to solve this problem. But

```
GetNamedPipeClientComputerName()
```

> ```
> Minimum supported client Windows Vista [desktop apps only]
> Minimum supported server Windows Server 2008 [desktop apps only]
> ```

Many client still using Windows XP.

I have searched a lot to solve the problem, but I could not find the code describing for this.

Thank you for all viewers.

Comment: See [`GetNamedPipeClientComputerName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365437.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Remy Lebeau. I tried to use that function before posting it, but the function is not defined. If you have any sample code, please send it.

Comment: Aha... GetNamedPipeClientComputerName() function supported onward Windows Vista!  But some client still using Windows XP. Is there any other way? Thank you very much Remy Lebeau.

Comment: you can get this info by `FSCTL_PIPE_GET_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE` (declared in *ntifs.h*) with `NtFsControlFile` (`DeviceIoControl` will be not correct work with this code). so if you ready use nt-api and very want xp support - not hard paste code - for this

Comment: Thank you for your help. RbMm, but I can't implement this as code. Excuse me, can you send me some sample code using NtFsControlFile and Attribute. It is painful because it does not work well.

Answer (score 1):

how already answered in comments [`GetNamedPipeClientComputerName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365437.aspx) can be used for this. it available from Windows Vista. if want it on xp also it can be implemented in next way:

```
ULONG AltGetNamedPipeClientComputerName(HANDLE Pipe, PWSTR ClientComputerName, ULONG ClientComputerNameLength)
{
    static const char AttributeName[] = "ClientComputerName";

    if (HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL))
    {
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

        NTSTATUS status = NtFsControlFile(Pipe,
            hEvent,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &iosb,
            FSCTL_PIPE_GET_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE,
            (void*)AttributeName,
            sizeof(AttributeName),
            ClientComputerName,
            ClientComputerNameLength*sizeof(WCHAR));

        if (status == STATUS_PENDING)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
            status = iosb.Status;
        }

        CloseHandle(hEvent);

        return status == STATUS_NOT_FOUND ? ERROR_PIPE_LOCAL : RtlNtStatusToDosError(status);
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```

this is general how really `GetNamedPipeClientComputerName` implemented internal. however if we use synchronous pipes (so created without `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`) we can simplify function - not need create event -  `NtFsControlFile` never return `STATUS_PENDING` for  synchronous handle.

```
ULONG AltGetNamedPipeClientComputerNameSync(HANDLE Pipe, PWSTR ClientComputerName, ULONG ClientComputerNameLength)
{
    static const char AttributeName[] = "ClientComputerName";

    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

    NTSTATUS status = NtFsControlFile(Pipe,
            hEvent,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &iosb,
            FSCTL_PIPE_GET_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE,
            (void*)AttributeName,
            sizeof(AttributeName),
            ClientComputerName,
            ClientComputerNameLength*sizeof(WCHAR));


    return status == STATUS_NOT_FOUND ? ERROR_PIPE_LOCAL : RtlNtStatusToDosError(status);
}
```

from another side if we use asynchronous pipe - we can and not wait when `FSCTL_PIPE_GET_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE` completed, but handle it asyncronous like other requests, which you handle async

one very important note - we can not use [`DeviceIoControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) here, but only [`NtFsControlFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566462(v=vs.85).aspx) - this is because [`DeviceIoControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) internally check `dwIoControlCode` and if it for `FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM` call [`NtFsControlFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566462(v=vs.85).aspx) otherwise [`NtDeviceIoControlFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566441(v=vs.85).aspx). the `FSCTL_PIPE_GET_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE` defined in `ntifs.h` (from wdk) as

```
#define FSCTL_PIPE_GET_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_NAMED_PIPE, 12, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
```

for `FILE_DEVICE_NAMED_PIPE` [`DeviceIoControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) call [`NtDeviceIoControlFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566441(v=vs.85).aspx) but we need [`NtFsControlFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566462(v=vs.85).aspx) exactly.

note that this worked only for server side pipe end (created by `CreateNamedPipe`) and in case client is remote. otherwise `STATUS_NOT_FOUND` will be returned from [`NtFsControlFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566462(v=vs.85).aspx). the `GetNamedPipeClientComputerName` implementation special check for this code and convert it to `ERROR_PIPE_LOCAL`